# jQuery .is(":visible) for an element which is absolute positioned out of viewport

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to find out if this is the correct way to get state of visibility of an div container which has    `position: absolute`.

I have a sidebar on the left of my viewport. When clicking the "sidebar-button" the "sideBar" gets animated out of the visible area.

jQuery:

```
$('#sideBarButton').click(function(){
    sidebar = $("#sideBar").outerWidth();
    if(!$("#sideBar").hasClass('outof'))
    {
       $("#sideBar").animate({left: screenW},100).addClass('outof');
       $("#boardContent").animate({width: screenW},200);
       $("#sideBarButton").animate({left: "+=" + (sidebar -3)},100);
    }
    else 
    {
       $("#boardContent").animate({width: bcW}, 50);
       setTimeout(function(){
           $("#sideBar").animate({left: screenW - sidebar}, 200).removeClass('outof');
           $("#sideBarButton").animate({left: "-=" + (sidebar -3)},200);
       }, 120);
    }
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

Since the sideBar now is not visible at all (for my eyes) and the left position of the sidebar is bigger than document.width my question is can I get the state of visibility (of sideBar) like this:

```
if($("#sideBar").is(":visible"))...
```

or is there a better way? I mean how does jQuery decide if an element is visible or not?

Comment: have a look at [jQuery Viewport](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport), a plugin with which you can determine if an element is visible easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote [jQuery itself](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.
>   Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible,
>   since they still consume space in the layout.

So with visible, jQuery does not take into account elements that are pulled out of the viewport. Eg. if you scroll down a page, the header is still deemed visible, although you cannot see it with the eye.

To check if the sidebar is visible, some (not so) complicated calculations have to be done by yourself, or just add a class or data attribute when the sidebar is out, like you have already done using the `outof` class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little test I ran to show you the results of your question: http://jsfiddle.net/dBgT3/

**HTML**

```
<div id="visible"></div>
<div id="hidden"></div>
<div id="offScreen"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $('body').append('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' - ' + $(this).is(':visible') + '<br />');
});
```

**CSS**

```
#hidden {
    display: none;
}

#offScreen {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000px;
}
```

**Results**

```
#visible - true
#hidden - false
#offScreen - false
```

It appears you are correct in assuming if the element is off screen it returns false. Hope this helps!

---

**Edit**
If the element that is positioned off screen has a set width or height the results will change.

**CSS**

```
div {
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px; 
}
```

**New Results**

```
#visible - true
#hidden - false
#offScreen - true
```

Thanks to giorgio for pointing that out!

Comment: Thank you! So finaly it is ok to check .is(":visible")

Comment: No problem. Sometimes the best way to find an answer is just to test it. :)

Comment: There is one problem with this: if you specifically size the divs, visible renders true, although it is not visible with the eye. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dBgT3/1/) for an example

Comment: Well caught! Interesting.

Comment: Wow - didn't expect this!

Comment: @ThomasTonius Just a followup as there was never a selected answer. Did you have any further questions?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of jQuery:

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.
>   Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible,
>   since they still consume space in the layout.
>
> Elements that are not in a document are considered to be hidden;
>   jQuery does not have a way to know if they will be visible when
>   appended to a document since it depends on the applicable styles.

This means that using left/right or margin-left/margin-right, will not work using ":visible" selector. I think what you need to do checking those values (for example if you are using left/right, use something like this:

```
if($("#sideBar").css("left") < 0)...  //(maybe parseInt will be needed here)
if(parseInt($("#sideBar").css("left")) < 0)...
```

I will use css classes and check if the class is already applied or not. For example ".slide-out" class will have the needed value for hiding the sidebar, and if the class is in the element then it is "hidden".

```
if($("#sideBar").hasClass("slide-out"))...
```

Also if you are going to use "left" property, maybe you need to look at "position().left"

```
$("#sideBar").position().left
```

Comment: I did this already - see "addClass('outof')" / "removeClass('outof')"

Answer (score 1):

With little testing it seems `:visible` doesn't consider if an item is on the screen or not.

http://jsfiddle.net/7uLg7/

From http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ :

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have >a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.
>
> Elements that are not in a document are considered to be hidden; **jQuery does not have a way to know if they will be visible when appended to a document since it depends on the applicable styles.**

To test if your sideBar is visible I think you have to take a harder route and test it's position and height/width against the size of the user's window taking scroll values into account.